# rust macro, convert $expr to different type

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

Currently I am working on the actor model, and I am using **macro** to build different messages, such as actor msg and system msg, based on the keyword.

`workload` to create a dummy workload to mock the computation process, it needs two args, `payload: usize`, and `op: OpCode(OperationType)`.

`create-actor` to create actors, two args are `count: uszie`, and `name: String`.

Workload and SystemCommand can be converted `Into` TypedMessage.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! build_msg {
    ($binary: expr, $arg1:tt, $arg2:expr) => {
        {
            let keyword: &str = $binary;
            match keyword {
                "workload" => {
                    let msg: TypedMessage = Workload::new($arg1 as usize,  $arg2 as OpCode).into();
                    msg
                }
                "create-actor" => {
                    let name: &str = arg2;
                    let msg:TypedMessage = SystemCommand::CreateActor($arg1 as usize, $name.to_owned()).into();
                    msg
                }
                _ => {
                    panic!("Unknow Keyword, or number of vars not match with Keyword");
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

However, I get an error: **mismatched types
expected struct `String`, found enum `messages::OpCode`**.

```
#[test]
    fn macro_build_msg_test() {
        let wl_macro_1: TypedMessage = build_msg!("workload", 2, OpCode::AddOp);  <- Problem here: OpCode::AddOp 
        assert_eq!(wl_macro_1, Workload::new(2, OpCode::AddOp).into());
    }
```

Based on the `keyword` and `match`, it should get into the different branch. So the args should be converted to the corresponding types. Why I get this error? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in your code, `$arg2:expr` has to have two different types at the same time, which is why you get an error saying as much.

You seem to want to combine different commands with their arguments and have tried to exploit some superficial resemblance between `workload` and `create-actor`, such as the number of parameters and their type. It is better to not try to rely on this and package a command with its arguments into one thing. You can do this with an enum:

```rust
enum Command {
    Workload { payload: usize, op: OperationType },
    CreateActor { count: usize, name: String },
}
```

Then you can match against the enum variants.

Finally, I don't see why you are trying to use a macro; maybe a normal function will do?

Comment: thanks. The reason I choose the macro is: there are a lot of different messages with different number of variables. Hence, I hope the macro could help me to avoid a lot of similar builder functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your macro to create a `match` with all the possibilities because all arms of the `match` would have to be valid for all types of inputs. Instead you should generate different code depending on the initial field:

```
macro_rules! build_msg {
    ("workload", $arg1:expr, $arg2:expr) => { {
        let msg: TypedMessage = Workload::new($arg1, $arg2).into();
        msg
    } };
    ("create-actor", $arg1:expr, $arg2:expr) => { {
        let msg: TypedMessage = SystemCommand::CreateActor($arg1, $arg2.to_owned()).into();
        msg
    } };
}
```

You can use it just as before: `build_msg!("workload", 2, OpCode::AddOp);` If the types are incorrect, or the first argument is not literally `"workload"` or `"create-actor"`, you'll get compile-time error.